# HttpWebRequest, HttpWebResponse stuck after a lot of request

Tags: c#

I write an application that acces to website and get html source, but after about 300 400 request, my httpwebrespond won't response and my application stuck.

Anyone know how to solved it ?

My code

```
HttpWebRequest RequestPage = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://domain.com/somepage.html");
RequestPage.Timeout = 30000;
RequestPage.Method = "GET";
RequestPage.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
RequestPage.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36";
string HtmlSourcePage = "";
using (HttpWebResponse RespondPage = (HttpWebResponse)RequestPage.GetResponse())
     {
        StreamReader StreamReaderPage = new StreamReader(RespondPage.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        HtmlSourcePage = StreamReaderPage.ReadToEnd();
        StreamReaderPage.Dispose();
        StreamReaderPage.Close();
        StreamReaderPage = null;
     }
```

RespondPage.Close();
   RequestPage.Abort();

Comment: There's `Concurrent Requests Limit` here that you should be aware of: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit

Comment: You should post your code so we can see what you're trying to do and why it isn't working.

Comment: Posted my code, hope all of you help me

Comment: You should not have `StreamReaderPage.Close(); StreamReaderPage = null;` after `StreamReaderPage.Dispose();`.

Comment: @andrew-morton Thanks, let's me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `maxconnection` of  connectionManagement in `app.config`/`web.config` file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
      <connectionManagement>
         <add address="*" maxconnection="500" />
      </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: C# Winform not ASP :(

Comment: It works with winforms too. just add an `app.config` file to the project (New Item -> Application Configuration File).